# Processing values in a column for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table of customers and the shop branches they have purchased from, similar to the following:

```
    customer_id   |   branch_id   |   is_major_branch
    -----------------------------------------------
        5               24                1
        5               83                0
        5               241               0
        8               66                0
        8               72                0
        9               15                1
        16              31                1
        16              61                1
```

`is_major_branch` is 1 if that branch is a particularly large store.

How can I delete all rows where a customer has shopped in a minor branch (is_major_branch = 0), *except* if a customer has only ever shopped in a minor branch? Example result set:

```
    customer_id   |   branch_id   |   is_major_branch
    -----------------------------------------------
        5               241               1
        8               66                0
        8               72                0
        9               15                1
        16              31                1
        16              61                1
```

Notice how customer 8 has only ever shopped in a minor branches, so we ignore them from the deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the rows doing:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select customer_id, max(is_major_branch) as max_is_major_branch
          from t
          group by customer_id
         ) tt
         on t.customer_id = tt.customer_id
    where t.is_major_branch = 0 and tt.max_is_major_branch = 1;
```

If you just want a `select` query, then use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not (t.is_major_branch = 0 and
           exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.customer_id = t.customer_id and t2.is_major_branch = 1)
          );
```